# Deduct 5% commission from a net value figure

Tags: sql

I wish to deduct 5% from a net value figure see explanation below:

In the COLLECT column I would like the following to be incorporated    BET * ([BetfairWinSP ]-1) * .95 + BET
The effect will be 5% commission deducted from BetfairWinSP -1

Example:  Bet = 1 BetfairWinSP = 5.0 Result = 1  outcome  5.0 -1 = 4.0 * .95 = 3.8 + 1 = 4.8 (Collect)

Please amend below code to effect this change. Many thanks, Ian

```
SELECT 
    Bet = COUNT(*) OVER ()
    , Collect = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN [BetfairWinSP ] END) OVER ()
    , Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN [BetfairWinSP ] END) OVER () - COUNT(*) OVER ()
```

Tried amending the code but being a complete novice failed miserably.

Comment: In most RDBMS you can't reference a derived column in the same select, you'll need to use a derived table or common table expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to include your calculation in your column definition. Can you do something like this?

```sql
SELECT
    Bet = COUNT(*) OVER (),
    Collect = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * 0.95 + 1) END) OVER (),
    Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN ([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * 0.95 END) OVER () - COUNT(*) OVER()
```

Comment: The Collect changes you made were perfect. however the profit didn't need changing and I reverted it back to the original code I supplied. All works great now many thanks

Comment: Oof, my bad. I got carried away. Glad everything worked out 